# Facebook like button disappears after page refresh (with jQuery)

Tags: jquery, facebook

I have facebook like button on my website like this:
`<fb:like href="'.URL.'" send="false" layout="box_count" width="450" show_faces="true" font="verdana"></fb:like>`

which is working fine until I put there jquery source code: 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>`
then facebook button disappears when I reload page by hitting f5 even though I'm not using any jquery script yet..

I found only solutions for twitter. Thanks.

Comment: Do you see any js error on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes time to load external js files. Put your reference to facebook api  `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>` just before the closing body tag `</body>`.  Hope it helps.